# EDM.Decimal decimal separator

Tags: odata, decimal, sapui5, separator

I'm just starting my first project with oData services and SAPUI5, after creating the first entity typs I'm facing a problem concerning decimal values.

I have created an entity type with edm.decimal core types. They are nullable, having prec. 8 and scale of 2 or 7 and 3 . The corresponding ABAP data types are 'CURR' oder 'QUAN'.

If I test the service for getting the single entity I receive the following error:

"Unable to interpret 0,01 as a number".

After changing the decimal separator of my user in the SU01 to '.' everything works fine. But in my opinion there must be a better way. I can't believe that I have to change every user in a company working in, for example germany to decimal separator '.'.

Do you have another solution for this problem?

Thank you for your help

Thomas

Comment: How do you test your oData? Are you using /IWFND/GW_CLIENT t-code?

Comment: Hi, yes I used this transaction and also google chrome.